# Getting Syntax error in query expression using LIKE CONCAT function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I am trying to fill in a column on a large table (1042sOutput), referencing another smaller table (1042sTransactions).

I need to take specific values from the 'GrossAmount' column (of the 1042sTransactions table) and input them into the '2_GrossIncome' column (of the 1042sOutput table).

The 1042sTransactions table has an 'AccountNumber' and 'IssueNumber' column that concatenates with another column from another table - for my purposes I don't need to include that table.  But I do need to match the concatenation of the 'AccountNumber' and 'IssueNumber' from the 1042sTransactions table to the 'ID' of the 1042sOutput table (but ignoring the first 3 digits of the 'ID' since that is pulled from a different table).

I keep getting an error:  "Syntax error in query expression 'b.ID LIKE CONCAT ('%', a.AccountNumber, a.IssueNumber'."

[Syntax error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT1Je.png)

Here is the Query:

```
SELECT

a.AccountNumber, 

a.GrossAmount,

a.IssueNumber,

b.ID

FROM
    1042sTransactions a INNER JOIN 1042sOutput b 

ON b.ID LIKE CONCAT (‘%’, a.AccountNumber, a.IssueNumber);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MS Access syntax for this query would be:

```
SELECT t.AccountNumber, t.GrossAmount, t.IssueNumber,o.ID
FROM 1042sTransactions as t INNER JOIN
     1042sOutput as o
     ON b.ID LIKE "*" & t.AccountNumber & IssueNumber;
```

Comment: Thanks again Gordon, I appreciate the help!